# Beego Session Not Passing Data to Template Automatically

Tags: session, go, beego

Upon getting session information of type `map[string]interface{}` with `this.GetSession("session_key")`, I did have to explicitly set the context and type assert the session like this in order to explicitly pass the data to the template.

```
// Get the session
profile := this.GetSession("profile")

// Have to add data to the template's context
this.Data["nickname"] = profile.(map[string]interface{})["nickname"].(string)
this.Data["picture"] = profile.(map[string]interface{})["picture"].(string)

// Render template
this.TplNames = "user.html"
```

The session data (type `map[string]interface{}`) looks like this:

```
{"nickname": "joe", "picture": "urltotheimg"}
```

However, according to the Beego's session [doc](http://beego.me/docs/mvc/controller/session.md),  it looks like the session is passed implicitly without any need of type assertions or context passing (the template has immediate access to session values i.e. `{{.nickname}}` and `{{.picture}}`)

This is the controller setting the session before redirecting to `/user`

```
// Inherit beego's base controller
type MyController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

func (this *MyController) Get() {

    // code for getting token here

    // Getting the User information
    client := conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext, token)
    resp, err := client.Get("https://" + domain + "/userinfo")
    if err != nil {
        this.Redirect("/error", 500)
        return
    }

    // Reading the body for user's information
    raw, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        this.Redirect("/error", 500)
        return
    }

    // Unmarshalling the JSON of the Profile
    var profile map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(raw, &profile); err != nil {
        this.Redirect("/error", 500)
        return
    }

    // Saving the information to the session.
    this.SetSession("profile", profile)

    // redirect to /user
    this.Redirect("/user", 301)
}
```

This is the controller of "/user"

```
type UserController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

func (this *UserController) Get() {
    // get the saved session
    profile := this.GetSession("profile")

    // without setting the template data here, the session data won't be
    // available in user.html
    this.Data["nickname"] = profile.(map[string]interface{})["nickname"].(string)
    this.Data["picture"] = profile.(map[string]interface{})["picture"].(string)
    this.TplNames = "user.html"
}
```

Only this then I can map the template to the data like this:

```
<img src="{{ .picture }}">
<p>Hello, {{ .nickname }}</p>
```

I'm quite sure it's necessary to set the template data. I'm just not sure why the above doc didn't do that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: I don't understand do I need to type assert the profile session and assign to Data map to reference the data in the template context. A few examples I saw just get the session and render the template and the data is available in the context.

Comment: @pie-o-pah I am too having trouble reading what is it that you expect to be displayed on the template. What's being rendered on your template? Because I see that your `<img src={{ .picture }}` is missing the **"**. Also, you are reading these values from the **Auth0Controller**. Are you sure these values are being set correctly? What happens if you just hardcode the values in UserController like: `this.Data["nickname"] = "User's Nickname"` and `this.Data["picture"] = "/path/to/img.jpg"`

Comment: @pie-o-pah Also, could you add to your question how you are configuring begoo and how your project's file and folder structure looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried running the [Beego quickstart](http://beego.me/docs/quickstart/) project and ran it successfully.

Make sure you have both the [beego](http://beego.me/docs/install) and [bee](http://beego.me/docs/install/bee.md) installed. After creating a new project with `bee new projectname` make sure you edit the **projectname/conf/app.conf** file and add the **sessionon = true**:

```
appname = quickstart
httpport = 8080
runmode = dev
sessionon = true
```

I created a redirect controller like:

```
type RedirectController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

func (c *RedirectController) Get() {
    profile := make(map[string]interface{})
    profile["nickname"] = "User's Nickname"
    profile["picture"] = "/path/to/img.jpg"

    c.SetSession("profile", profile)
    c.Redirect("/", 301)
}
```

The main controller:

```
type MainController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

func (c *MainController) Get() {
    profile := c.GetSession("profile")

    c.Data["nickname"] = profile.(map[string]interface{})["nickname"]
    c.Data["picture"] = profile.(map[string]interface{})["picture"]
    c.TplNames = "index.tpl"
}
```

My index.tpl file:

```
<p>Nickname: {{.nickname}}</p>
<p>Picture: {{.picture}}</p>
```

And the router:

```
func init() {
    beego.Router("/", &controllers.MainController{})
    beego.Router("/redirect", &controllers.RedirectController{})
}
```

I would also recommend you to use a structure to store the profile values like:

```
// Define struct.
type Profile struct{
    Nickname string
    Picture  string
}

// Save it for template rendering.
this.Data["profile"] = &Profile{Nickname:"astaxie", Picture:"img.jpg"}

// And render it like this:
Nickname: {{.profile.Nickname}}
Picture:  {{.profile.Picture}}
```

Make sure to read [this](http://beego.me/docs/mvc/view/view.md#template-data) to understand how template rendering is done. I hope this is what you were asking for, if not, please edit your question and add more helpful information and I will edit this answer.

Comment: Thanks I totally missed the part that Beego always need to set template data with `this.Data[]` while in vanilla Go the data can be passed into the `RenderTemplate` method. Still, thanks for pointing out!